# Cassandra 1.2 : Updating type in primary Key CQL3

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We currently have a table defined as below

```
create table tableA(id int,
                    seqno int,                    
                    data text,
                    PRIMARY KEY((id), seqno))
                    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (seqno DESC);
```

We need to update the type for the id column from int to text. We are wondering out of the two approaches, would be the most advisable.

1. ALTER TABLE tableA ALTER id TYPE varchar; (the command succeeds but then we have issues reading the data. Is this because the ALTER table doesn't update the underlying storage of the id column?)
2. COPY to/from oldtable/newtable. This works but we have issues with the RPC timeout (which we can change), but is this a bad idea on a table across a cluster?

We have checked the online docs and these are only 2 options we can find around this. are there other options??

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2):

I would say option 1 isn't really supported. If your integers don't map to actual strings you're going to have problem, you're probably seeing key validation errors.

for option 2 you probably just need to copy smaller chunks of data for each read/write.